# Matching Strings in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors of strings:

```
vec1 <- c("hellohi", "good", "goodafternoonabc")

vec2 <- c("helloworld", "goodmorning", "abc")
```

Is there a function that matches patterns within the two vectors, such that :

`function(vec1, vec2)` return matches : "hello", "good", "good", "abc" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would look into fuzzyjoin package on cran: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You can use %in% to check the matches, which creates a T F vector that can then be used for indexing against vec1.

```
vec1[vec1 %in% vec2]
```

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wants... returns `numeric(0)` in this case because none of the elements of vec1 are in vec2 (e.g. "hellohi" is not an element of vec2)

Comment: This is not a trivial problem and the solution will need to know what words are.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it looks more like just wanted to extract the longest possible matching string rather than actually knowing what words are.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry about that - guess I didn't actually fully read what OP was looking for.